# Power Query Updating a row

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am trying to do this in Power BI. Whether DAX or Power Query anything would be useful.

I have 2 columns one is 'Date' and the other is 'Version Number'.

I want to update the dates where 'Version Number' is Version_1 and 'Date' is blank to the dates where 'Version Number' is Version_2 and 'Date' is not blank.

Basically if Version_2 has a date and Version_1 doesn't have a date then the dates of these Version_2 should be copied to Version_1 dates.

Tried nested ifs in power query and DAX but not able to achieve the desired result.

***Problem and desired result. I hope this helps***
[image: .]

Comment: Can you please update with example table and desired result?

Comment: I have added an image with the problem and desired result.

Comment: Do either of these answer work for you? If so, please toggle checkmark to mark as solved and upvote it

Answer (score 0):

One way in powerquery

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content], 
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),
#"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Version Number] = "Version_2") and ([Date] <> null))), 
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"Project Number"}, #"Removed Duplicates", {"Project Number"}, "TableA", JoinKind.LeftOuter), 
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Merged Queries",{{"Date", "Date3"}, {"Version Number", "Version Number3"}}), 
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Date", each if [Version Number3]="Version_1" then [TableA]{0}[Date] else [Date3]), 
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Version Number", each if [Version Number3]="Version_1" then [TableA]{0}[Version Number]  else[Version Number3]), 
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Date3", "Version Number3", "TableA"}) 
in #"Removed Columns"
```

or

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content], 
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type","Date2",(x)=>try Date.From(Table.SelectRows(Source, each x[Project Number]=[Project Number] and x[Version Number]="Version_1" and [Version Number]="Version_2")[Date]{0}) otherwise x[Date],type date),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Added Custom","Version_1","Version_2",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Version Number"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Replaced Value",{"Date"}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Date2", "Date"}})
in  #"Renamed Columns"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See code comments to better understand algorithm:

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table14"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Project Number", Int64.Type}, {"Date", type date}, {"Version Number", type text}}),

//Add index column to retain original sort order
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

/*Group by Project Number
   then replace null dates for Version_1 with first date for Version_2*/
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Index", {"Project Number"}, {
        {"Date", (t)=>
            let 
                dt = Table.SelectRows(t, each [Version Number] = "Version_2"){0}[Date]
            in 
                Table.ReplaceValue(t,
                    each [Date],
                    each if [Version Number] = "Version_1" and [Date] = null then dt else [Date],
                    Replacer.ReplaceValue,
                    {"Date"}),
                type table [Project Number=nullable number, Date=nullable date, Version Number=nullable text, Index=Int64.Type]
       }}),

/*Remove Project number column
   then expand the subtables*/
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Project Number"}),
    #"Expanded Date" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Date", 
        {"Project Number", "Date", "Version Number", "Index"}),

/*Sort back to original order using Index column
   then remove the Index column*/
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Date",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

***Before***
[image]

***After***
[image]